# DataGrid Binding Column with function replace()

Tags: wpf

i have a little  question

i have a datagrid

and i want to do

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding **replace(Code_pr,'_', 'PDT')**}" Width="100" Header="Code product"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

any one have solution please

Comment: Not in XAML, but that's what converters are for. Implement the IValueConverter Interface and integrate you replacement logic there. You'll find a lot about converters here. Or do you need further help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this.

It would looke something like this:

```
public class ReplaceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString().Replace('_','PDT');
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString().Replace('PDT','_');
    }
}
```

Add it as a resource in your XAML:

```
<src:ReplaceConverter x:Key="replaceConverter"/>
```

Change the binding:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Code_pr, Converter={StaticResource replaceConverter}}" Width="100" Header="Code product"/>
```